# PHP scrape links from table

Tags: php, web-scraping

How to get only one link from the table?

```
<table>
        <tr class="title">
        <td width="40%">a </td>
        <td width="40%">b</td>
        <td width="10%">c</td>
        <td width="10%">d</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>abc.com</td>
        <td>123.123.526.12</td>
        <td><a class="update" href="fruit/grape"</a></td>
        <td><a class="delete" href="fruit/grape"></a></td>
        <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>bcd.com</td>
        <td>123.256.33.123</td>
        <td><a class="update" href="fruit/apple"></a></td>
        <td><a class="delete" href="fruit/apple"></a></td>
        <td> </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

my code:

```
$html_doc = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$html_doc->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();
$html_xpath = new DOMXPath($html_doc);

$link1 = $html_xpath->query('//table/tr[not(contains(@class,"title"))]');
foreach($link1 as $a)
{   
    $bac = $a->nodeValue;
    echo $bac."<br>";
    $rows = $a->getElementsByTagName("a");
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        echo $row->getAttribute("href")."<br>";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 abc.com 123.123.526.12
    fruit/grape
    fruit/grape
    bcd.com 123.256.33.123
    fruit/apple
    fruit/apple
```

The code above return 2 href attribute to me. my expected output is one href attribute for each row.

My expected Output:

```
        abc.com 123.123.526.12
        fruit/grape
        bcd.com 123.256.33.123
        fruit/apple
```

How can i do it to fit my expected output?

Comment: would you post out the output generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that is because you echo each anchor. You could put them in an array and check if you have already collected that link:

```
$all_links = array();

foreach($link1 as $a)
{   
    $bac = $a->nodeValue;
    $all_links[$bac] = array();
    $rows = $a->getElementsByTagName("a");

    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        $href = $row->getAttribute("href");
        if (!in_array($href, $all_links[$bac])) {
            $all_links[$bac][] = $href;
        }
    }
}
```

Link to fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/e9y3-23gw

My output:

```
Array
(
    [abc.com        123.123.526.12] => Array
        (
            [0] => fruit/grape
        )

    [bcd.com        123.256.33.123] => Array
        (
            [0] => fruit/apple
        )

)
```

Comment: No it doesn't, you have to use the `$all_links` instead. Try a `var_dump($all_links)`. I've updated my answer with the output I get.